# Bloodshed Dev-C++ compiler errors *Binary Trees

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, binary-tree, dev-c++

I would like feedback on my code please. It is an assignment for school where we were asked to write a function that swaps the left and right side binary trees. Our class that our professor gave us was swapBinaryTrees and the rest was left up to us. I am getting a whole lot of compiler errors and I am not sure where I am going wrong with my syntax. I am getting errors when I compile it like line 14 expected init-declarator '<'token the line in reference is

```
void binaryTreeSearch<elemType>::swapSubtreeNodes()
```

I have the same error for line 19 which is

```
void binaryTreeSearch<elemType>::swapSubtreeNodes(nodeType<elemType> *p)
```

for both of the above I have another error that says expecting ';' before '<' token
Then I get undeclared identifier in my main function for

```
binaryTreeSearch<int> tree;
```

I also am getting expected primary expression before "int" and expected ';' before "int"
then it tells me that cout and cin are not declared I do not know what the haybales is going on here. I will post my whole code below, any help is greatly appreciated.

```
template <class elemType>
struct nodeType
{
       elemType info;
       nodeType<elemType> *lLink;
       nodeType<elemType> *rLink;
};
template <class elemType>
class swapSubtreeNodes
{

};
template <class elemType>
void binaryTreeSearch<elemType>::swapSubtreeNodes()
{
     swapSubtreeNodes(root);
}
template <class elemType>
void binaryTreeSearch<elemType>::swapSubtreeNodes(nodeType<elemType> *p)
{
    root = temp;
    nodeType<elemType> *root;
    nodeType<elemType> *temp;
    if (p == null)
    {
          return;
    }
    else
    {
        swapSubtreeNodes(p->lLink);
        swapSubtreeNodes(p->rLink);                                  
        temp = p->lLink;
        p->lLink = p->rLink;
        p->rLink = temp;
    }
}
int main()
{
    binaryTreeSearch<int> tree;
    int num;
    cout << "This is how we swap'em" << endl;
    cout << "Insert number (press enter after each one entered)." << endl;
    cout << "Enter -999 to complete" << endl;
    tree.insert(0);
    cin >> num;
    while (num != -999)
    {
          tree.insert(num);
          cin >> num;
    }
    cout << "Your swapped binary tree is " << endl;
         tree.swapSubtreeNodes();
         tree.printTree();
         cout << endl;


}
```

Comment: The latest version of Dev-C++ was released in 2005. It is very old and outdated, please consider upgrading to a modern one like GCC or Visual C++.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: There is a fork here: http://orwelldevcpp.blogspot.fr/ which seems well maintained.

Comment: @AlexandreC. Thank you for the info, I didn't know of any forks. I will recommend that to people in the future.

Comment: @bitmask Homework tag is in the process of being blacklisted, please do not add it to the question. See the tag for more info.

Comment: @Tim: The tag wiki says "But don't remove it without looking at the question to see if it needs cleanup." The question however, specifically states that it is about homework.

Comment: @bitmask I'm not sure what point you're trying to make. It's perfectly fine for a question to be about homework, but it's been decided that the tag 'homework' should no longer exist, and an effort is being undertaken to remove it. In my opinion there's nothing else wrong with this question that needs to be addressed.

Comment: @Tim: I see, thanks for the clarification. I wasn't trying to make any particular point, I just wasn't aware of this recent decision.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't declare the `binaryTreeSearch` type. Therefore you cannot implement member functions for it. Your compiler is telling you that it has no clue what you mean by

```
template <class elemType>
void binaryTreeSearch<elemType>::swapSubtreeNodes()
```

at the position with `<` because it doesn't understand that you intend `binaryTreeSearch` to be a class.

---

What you are doing when you write:

```
template <class elemType>
void binaryTreeSearch<elemType>::swapSubtreeNodes()
{
     swapSubtreeNodes(root);
}
```

is this; You are telling C++ that you intend to implement a member function `swapSubTreeNodes` of type `int ()()` that belongs to a structured type (i.e. a `class` or a `struct`) of the name `binaryTreeSearch` which is templated with one parameter. However, your compiler (any compiler really) complains because there is no such type. How you fix this issue depends on what you really intended to do. One option could be declaring that type:

```
template <class elemType>
class binaryTreeSearch // I really recommend to write types Uppercase!
{
  private:
    nodeType<elemType>* root;
    //                  ^---- that's the variably you are trying to
    //                        access in your original post
  public:
    void swapSubtreeNodes();
    void swapSubtreeNodes(nodeType<elemType>*);
};
```

This will not fix all errors but is probably what you intended to do. You may also want to add a proper constructor and destructor.

Comment: So I should be declaring it as "class" binaryTreeSearch instead?

Comment: @Angie: I'm really not sure what's tripping you off, here. Let me rephrase the answer.

Comment: okay figured out what you were talking about and updated my code (see above edit on main code). Now have one more error that I am unsure of. Thanks.

Comment: @Angie: This is not how it works. Reduce your example to the minimum and open a separate question (you can link this one). The original issue appears to be solved.