# dev-c++ compiler error no matching function

Tags: c++, binary-tree

I was working this code previously but have a new issue with it the link to the old one is [Bloodshed Dev-C++ compiler errors *Binary Trees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12438661/bloodshed-dev-c-compiler-errors-binary-trees).

I have one error that states in function 'int main()' no matching function for call to 'binaryTreeType::insert(int&)' candidates are: void binaryTreeType::insert () [with elemType = int] not really sure what this is. The code is posted below any help is appreciated thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class elemType>
struct nodeType
{
       int data;
       nodeType *lLink;
       nodeType *rLink;
};
template <class elemType>
class binaryTreeType //main class
{
      public:
             binaryTreeType(); //constructor
             ~binaryTreeType(); //destructor
             void swapSubtreeNodes(); //declares swapSubtreeNodes
             void swapSubtreeNodes(nodeType<elemType>*);
             void insert();
             void printTree();
      private:
              nodeType<elemType>*root; //declares root pointer
              nodeType<elemType> *temp; //declares root pointer
};
template <class elemType>
void binaryTreeType<elemType>::swapSubtreeNodes()
{
     swapSubtreeNodes(root); //displays new root
}
template <class elemType>
void binaryTreeType<elemType>::swapSubtreeNodes(nodeType<elemType> *p)
{
    root = temp;
    nodeType<elemType> *root; //pointer for root
    nodeType<elemType> *temp; //pointer for temp
    if (p == NULL) //checks for empty pointer
    {
          return;
    }
    else
    {
        swapSubtreeNodes(p->lLink); //do the subtrees
        swapSubtreeNodes(p->rLink);                                  
        temp = p->lLink; //swap the pointers
        p->lLink = p->rLink;
        p->rLink = temp;
    }
    root = temp; //root set equal to temp
}
int main()
{
    binaryTreeType<int> (tree);
    int num;
    cout << "This is how we swap'em" << endl;
    cout << "Insert number (press enter after each one entered)." << endl;
    cout << "Enter -999 to complete" << endl;
    binaryTreeType<int> (insert);
    cin >> num;
    while (num != -999)
    {
          tree.insert(num);
          cin >> num;
    }
    cout << "The unswapped binary tree looks like this: " << endl;
         tree.printTree();
         cout << endl;
    cout << "The swapped binary tree looks like this: " << endl;
         tree.swapSubtreeNodes();
         tree.printTree();
         cout << endl;


 }
```

Comment: The error is pretty clear. You've declared `insert` as taking *no* arguments, yet later you want to call it with *one* argument.

Comment: `tree.insert(num);` is passing an argument to a function that takes none.

Comment: Just as a matter of style, you don't need parentheses in `binaryTreeType<int> (tree);`, and it looks confusing. Make it `binaryTreeType<int> tree;`.

Comment: @PeteBecker, I was trying to figure out what `binaryTreeType<int> (insert);` was when I was just looking for signs of the error. Confusing is right.

Answer (score 1):

The template member function `binaryTreeType<elemType>::insert()` takes no arguments. The code tries to call it with an argument of type `int`.

Comment: Still not getting what I am doing wrong, I am sorry. I have tried changing my declaration of "void insert ();" from my "class binaryTreeType" a bunch of different ways and I am different errors each time I try something different but none of them are solving my original issue.

Comment: @Angie - show some code. Most likely, the argument type should be `elemType` or const `elemType&`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `insert` method declaration doesn't take any parameters.